# How to set UTC offset for datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

My Python-based web server needs to perform some date manipulation using the client's timezone, represented by its UTC offset. How do I construct a datetime object with the specified UTC offset as timezone?

Comment: The builtin date utils are good, but somewhat limited; take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/ and http://labix.org/python-dateutil for more convenient TZ handling.

Comment: I presume you don't know the actual zone name, just the offset?

Comment: Can you specify the format of the offset? Integer hours? String of some kind?

Comment: To echo Mark's point - Make sure you understand that an offset is not a time zone.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3d387704d4a18db5aea758e9a26c1ee4d71659df/celery/utils/time.py#L320

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import dateutil.tz
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 0, 17, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset(None, 9*60*60))
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 0, 17, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 32400))
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 0, 17, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset('KST', 9*60*60))
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 0, 17, tzinfo=tzoffset('KST', 32400))
```

---

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2013/09/11 00:17 +0900')
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 0, 17, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 32400))
```

Comment: with dateutil version 2.8.2 (and probably others), you need `import dateutil.parser` to then call `dateutil.parser.parse`.

Answer (score 25):

As an aside, Python 3 (since v3.2) now has a [timezone class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) that does this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

# offset is in seconds
utc_offset = lambda offset: timezone(timedelta(seconds=offset))

datetime(*args, tzinfo=utc_offset(x))
```

However, note that "objects of this class cannot be used to represent timezone information in the locations where different offsets are used in different days of the year or where historical changes have been made to civil time." This is generally true of any time zone conversion relying strictly on UTC offset.

Comment: Thanks. This helped out a lot and works a lot better than the insane suggestions of making subclasses of tzinfo for each individual timezone like I have been finding over the internet.

Answer (score 8):

The [`datetime` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) contains an example `tzinfo` class that represents a fixed offset.

```
ZERO = timedelta(0)

# A class building tzinfo objects for fixed-offset time zones.
# Note that FixedOffset(0, "UTC") is a different way to build a
# UTC tzinfo object.

class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """Fixed offset in minutes east from UTC."""

    def __init__(self, offset, name):
        self.__offset = timedelta(minutes = offset)
        self.__name = name

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.__offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.__name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO
```

Since Python 3.2 it is no longer necessary to provide this code, as [`datetime.timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone) and [`datetime.timezone.utc`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone.utc) are included in the `datetime` module and should be used instead.

Comment: Might be worth noting that a functionally equivalent class is available in pytz: https://git.launchpad.net/pytz/tree/src/pytz/__init__.py?id=1ce6a27c1ee27fc358ed5cc34b88ae36435cc9be#n415

Comment: @GordStephen you're always free to leave your own answer. Newer versions of Python include the `timezone` class so I'm going to update my answer for that, thanks for saying something.