# Python is not able update the time according to selected timezone in inux

Tags: python, linux, datetime

Python is not able update the time according to selected timezone in inux.

I have python code which just trying to print time in ISO format using python date time module as in below code.

```
{

import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

print current_time

}
```

I am trying to run this code in the startup script of linux. 
I have set the time zone in the linux as `UTC-05:30`. But still I am getting "current_time" as in UTC and not in `UTC-05:30`. The "current_time" is lags behind the system time by `05:30` hours.
I am really sure why python is not able to use the system time during the boot up.
Please let me know anybody know about this issue.

My problem has to do something about the starting python script at bootup. I think Linux is not able to set its time according to timezone at bootup . I have printed system time at boot up which is in UTC and not in UTC-05:30 though my timezone is UTC-05:30. Since my script is starting at bootup,it took system time which is set according to UTC and not UTC-05:30. Once the system boots up, system time is set correctly according to timezone.I will get correct output for date command. But some how my python application is not able get the time according to timezone.

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722196/how-to-set-utc-offset-for-datetime

Comment: I doubt that `.now()` returns utc time unless your local timezone has zero utc offset. What is `datetime.utcnow()` in your case? Does `date` command show the expected local time?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The date command at startup wont show expected local time. But when machine boots up completely, date command will show expected time.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The datetime.utcnow() is same as datetime.now()