# Convert string time with offset from UTC to UTC unix

Tags: python, datetime, time, date-conversion

How to convert string time with offset from UTC to UTC unix?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the actual problem is. Also, I doubt that this hasn't been answered here already.

Comment: I did about 10 different queries on Google and none of the solutions worked for me. Input: — String time, like '27.06.2022 12:35', — Offset from UTC of this string time, e.g. -4 (UTC-4). Output: — Unix in UTC ('27.06.2022 12:35 UTC-4' -> '27.06.2022 16:35 UTC' -> 1656347700)

Comment: what about [How to set UTC offset for datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18722196/10197418)? ok, I admit, if you encounter a problem first time, it's sometimes hard to know in advance what to search for...

Comment: It's only useful info about offset working, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta


def strtime_to_unix(str_time: str, utc_offset: int, format: str = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M') -> int:
    return int(datetime.strptime(str_time, format).replace(
        tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(seconds=utc_offset * 60 * 60))).timestamp())


str_time = '27.06.2022 12:35'

print(strtime_to_unix(str_time, 0))  # 12:35 UTC -> 1656333300
print(strtime_to_unix(str_time, -4))  # 16:35 UTC -> 1656347700
print(strtime_to_unix(str_time, 3))  # 09:35 UTC -> 1656322500
```

Output:

```
1656333300
1656347700
1656322500
```

Comment: You could simplify to using a [timezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) object, created from a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), so you don't need to import dateutil.

Comment: ...similar to as it is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24579002/10197418